# Why can't a DataFrame Index be used for data dictionary lookup in .apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a DataFrame and a Dictionary. I want to assign values to a new column in the DataFrame based on the Dictionary.

```
ContinentDictionary  = {'United States':'North America', 
                        'Japan':'Asia', 
                        'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                        'Australia':'Australia', 
                        'Argentina':'South America'}

c1 = pd.Series({'Size':'Large','Pi':6,'Pr':160})
c2 = pd.Series({'Size':'Small','Pi':9,'Pr':235})
c3 = pd.Series({'Size':'Large','Pi':12,'Pr':300})
Countries = pd.DataFrame([c1,c2,c3],index=['United States','Japan','United Kingdom'])
Countries.index.name='Country'
```

This gets the job done, assigning a continent to each country in the Countries DataFrame:

```
Countries['Continent'] = Countries.index.map(lambda x: ContinentDictionary[x])
```

This also works, but I need to set the index 'Country' as a column beforehand to make .apply work:

```
Countries['Continent'] = Countries.reset_index(inplace = True)
Countries['Continent'] = Countries.apply(lambda x: ContinentDictionary[x['Country']], axis=1)
```

I'd like to get a better understanding as to why these two approaches don't work and would be grateful for an explanation:

1. `Countries['Continent'] = Countries.apply(lambda x: ContinentDictionary[x.index], axis=1)`
2. `Countries['Continent'] = ContinentDictionary[Countries.index]`

Both give:

```
TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'Index'"
```

Of the two, I can imagine why #2 might not work but would still love to understand better.

Comment: Variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Also, may I ask why you’re setting the name of the country as the index, instead of simply having it as a column?

Comment: Thank you, I will take note of the proper convention! The name of the country as the index is the data set I was given to work with. I did change it as a column and was able to make .apply() work as in the above. But I still don't get why I can pass index (#1 above).

Comment: The `apply()` method can be simplified to `countries_df['country_name'].map(continent_dict)`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends of version of pandas, in oldier versions is necessary add `.get`, also solution is simplify with remove lambda and pass only `dictionary`:

```
Countries['Continent'] = Countries.index.map(ContinentDictionary.get)
print (Countries)
                 Size  Pi   Pr      Continent
United States   Large   6  160  North America
Japan           Small   9  235           Asia
United Kingdom  Large  12  300         Europe
```

EDIT: From version [pandas 0.23+](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.23.0.html#other-api-changes) is possible use dictionary or Series for mapper:

> **Index.map()** can now accept Series and dictionary input objects (GH12756, GH18482, GH18509).

Comment: Thank you, yes, I am using that solution. Also, I was using .get in my first attempts but that didn't work either. I don't understand why you can't pass the index when you can pass a cell value.

Comment: Nice, I can’t believe I forgot `Index.map()` was a thing. @jammer_man

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks, I got that solution prior to posting. But I want to understand why passing the Index in the apply function doesn't work. I'm just not happy with my superficial understanding.

Comment: @jammer_man It has nothing to do with `apply()`, it’s the fact that it can’t be used as the key to a dictionary. Even if it could, I don’t think the code makes much sense: You’re passing the entire index as the key! Replace the Index type with a List when you’re thinking about it, it makes it a bit simpler.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I thought axis=1 doesn't make me pass the entire index as the key but a single index instead? In my post above, if I made the index as a column ('Country') instead, I can pass it as x['Country'], which works perfectly fine. Converting the index into a string doesn't work as well because like you said, it does appear like I am still passing the entire index. So you're saying, I just cand use an "index" value as a key to a dictionary and there is no way to convert an index to a string?

Comment: @jammer_man I'm trying to think of the best way of sharing multiple lines of output to demonstrate something....

Comment: @jammer_man Can’t believe I forgot to answer this. You can convert the Index into a string, that’s what I showed in my answer. Unfortunately you’re correct, yes, you can’t use it as a key to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to a few of your comments.

---

You wrote *I thought axis=1 doesn't make me pass the entire index as the key but a single index instead?* I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean, so let me try to clarify something.

With `axis=1`, the function operates on rows. Each row is converted to a **Series**. Here is an example of what one of the rows looks like as a Series:

```
Size    Large
Pi          6
Pr        160
Name: United States, dtype: object
```

When you call `x.index`, you're expecting to receive the index of row `x` **in the DataFrame**. In fact, you get the index of the **Series** `x`:

```
Index(['Size', 'Pi', 'Pr'], dtype='object')
```

*So you're saying, I just cand use an "index" value as a key to a dictionary and there is no way to convert an index to a string?* Index objects cannot be used as keys in a dictionary, or in any situation that requires a hashable object. You can convert them to strings, as I just did above.

---

As @Jezrael mentions in the comments, calling `.apply()` on a Series gets you the individual elements, which in this case do not have an index.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it and I feel like an idiot. I had thought the whole time that axis=1 returns a row (not necessarily a Series) where I can access each element.
  
I had imaged the the row to look something like this:  

`Index: 'Japan' . 
`Size: 'Small' . 
`Pi: 9 . 
`Pr: 300 . 
  
It felt convenient to access what I thought the 'Index' would be via something like: row.index

Comment: this is in contrast to being able to get and use the index for the row through: `for index, row in Countries.iterrows(): print(index)`

Comment: @jammer_man The index for the row **in the DataFrame**, yes. The row has its own index in `.apply()`.